# Unable to connect to access database using php

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc, wampserver

I am unable to connect to access database through php.
I have searched the internet for the issue. It is my 3rd day, I am trying this but could not find the solution.
I have installed all the required things: ODBC drivers and MS Access Database engine.

My php code to connect to database named newDB.mdb is:

```
<?php 
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "access_db/newDB.mdb";
echo $dbName."<br />";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
die("Could not find database file.<br />".$dbName);
}
try {
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq=$dbName");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />";
}
?>
```

The error I receive:

```
C:/wamp/www/access_db/newDB.mdb
Error: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
>Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I am working on a local machine.

OS: Windows8 Pro, and WampServer 2.5, Microsoft Access 2013 (I am exporting the file as .mdb, it also doesn't work for .accdb extension)

I don't know what I am lacking, or what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your driver name is missing a space. It should be

```
DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}
                                       ^
```

Comment: Gord...Can you please have a look at this if you have time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774178/odbc-call-failed-with-stored-procedure-pass-through-query

Comment: I have added this space but still getting the same error.

Comment: @zDepco - Have your code `echo (8 * PHP_INT_SIZE) . "-bit";` and make sure that it matches the "bitness" of the version of Access 2013 you have installed (64-bit or 32-bit).

Comment: This line prints "32-bit" and my access version is also 32-bit 
( In about access, it displays: Microsoft Access 2013 (15.0.4701.1001) MSO (15.0.4701.1000) 32-bit   )

Answer (score 0):

As long as just needing to support .mdb-files, you can try this:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName");
```

This worked fine for me.

It seems, on default the "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" is not installed. Open `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` in the register card `Drivers`.

In my case - I think that's the standart office/access installation behavior - ther was just the `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)`.

If you need to support .accdb-files, you'll need to install the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable": https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255

After installing, you can use

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver 
(*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq=$dbName");
```

**Edit:**

I found a newer version for my installation of Office 2016 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) but was unable to install.
I got errors reporting for using 64-bit office components, but 32-bit office is installed. Anybody an idea to solve the problem?