# ODBC Call Failed with stored procedure - Pass through query

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, linked-tables

I have created a pass through query and trying to call a stored procedure  from it.

I am able to execute the queries on sql server database sucessfully but when it comes to stored procedures, i am getting an error as :

"`ODBC call Failed"`

The problem is with stored procedures only. The queries are executing fine .

**Here , is my code :**

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim Server As String
ServerName = "XXXX"
DatabaseName = "XXX"
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
 strConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER={sql server};" & _
        "DATABASE=" & DatabaseName & ";" & _
        "SERVER=" & ServerName & ";" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=YES;"
qdf.Connect = strConnectionString
qdf.SQL = " EXEC [dbo].[SAMPLE_TEST]"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
Debug.Print rst!RecordCount
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

**Please let me know if i am missing any thing ?**

Comment: What happens if you change `rst As ADODB.Recordset` to `rst As DAO.Recordset`?

Comment: @HansUp..The same error

Comment: What does the stored procedure do?  Does it return rows?

Comment: select count(*) as RecordCount from tablename ..just a normal select query

Comment: @HansUp..all the queries are running directly but when kept inside a sp , it is saying ODBC call failed.

Comment: can you create a passthrough query from ms access design view and try your sql code there? is it working there?

Comment: give your queryDef a name. close the querydef and perfom a normal select * from your querydef and see if thats working.

Comment: @Krish..in every other case it is working , only if i put that SQL statement in the stored proc , it is throwing the error message

Comment: Try trapping the 3146 error and then looping through the `DBEngine.Errors` collection as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161288). That might give you something more to work with than just "ODBC--call failed."

Comment: @GordThompson..will do it and get back to you..

Comment: @GordThompson..i have trapped the error : Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SAMPLE_TEST', database 'XXX, schema 'dbo'.

Comment: @GordThompson..But i could not understand why it is showing this error. I have created this stored proc and able to execute from SQL server Management studio

Comment: @GordThompson..Thank you very much, It was access issue , igranted execute permission for that sp and then it is working absolutely fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get more information about the cause of an "ODBC--call failed." error we can loop through the `DBEngine.Errors` collection and see if there are other messages that might be a bit more descriptive. For example, with the code

```vbs
    qdf.Connect = strConnectionString
    qdf.SQL = " EXEC [dbo].[SAMPLE_TEST]"
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
    On Error GoTo oops
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
    Debug.Print rst!RecordCount
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Sub
oops:
    Dim dbeError As Error
    For Each dbeError In DBEngine.Errors
        Debug.Print "(" & dbeError.Number & "): " & dbeError.Description
    Next
End Sub
```

we might see the following in the VBA Immediate window:

```
(229): [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SAMPLE_TEST', database 'myDb', schema 'dbo'.
(3146): ODBC--call failed.
```

Certainly

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SAMPLE_TEST', database 'myDb', schema 'dbo'.

is considerably more helpful than just

> ODBC--call failed.

Comment: @Gord...This certainly helped. Accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just looked over your code again. You are not running the qry

Wouldnt you need to do `qry.execute`?

Comment: If a DAO.QueryDef object returns records then `qdf.OpenRecordset` executes the query and returns the results as a DAO.Recordset. If QueryDef does not return records then `qdf.Execute` is used.