# T-SQL how to update the value of an int field from another nvarchar field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to update an int field of ODBC linked SQL Server table in my Access DB, from another nvarchar field, with following codes. But it fails to run, I don't know what I missed, appreciate if someone can help. Thanks a lot.

```
Function update_test()
Dim qryd As QueryDef
Set qryd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qryd.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=ODBC11;"
qryd.SQL = "UPDATE table1 SET int_field = CAST(text_field AS int)"
qryd.ReturnsRecords = False
qryd.Execute
End Function
```

My ODBC connection is correct and stable, and the following code can be run successfully, that's why I am confused why above codes cannot be run.

These codes can be run succesfully:

```
Function update_test()
Dim qryd As QueryDef
Set qryd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qryd.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=ODBC11;"
qryd.SQL = "UPDATE table1 SET int_field = other_int_field"
qryd.ReturnsRecords = False
qryd.Execute
End Function
```

Comment: What exactly is "it fails to run" ?

Comment: Hi @Andre451, there is no clear error message, when try to debug, this line is highlighted "qryd.Execute". Thanks.

Comment: Hi Andre451, I have run the query directly in the SQL Server instead of Acess, and SQL Server directly shows the exact cause of the problem. It is the data issue, it is now fixed. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry all, the above question is solved. There is some problem with the data itself, there are some non-numberic data in text_field. My apology. I try to run the SQL query in the SQL Server instead of Access, the SQL server clearly shows where is the cause of the problem. So, if you encounter TSQL issue in Access with unknown reason, you can try to execute the same query in SQL Server again and see if SQL server points out what exactly goes wrong. My aplogize for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: You can also get more information than just "ODBC--call failed" on the Access side by inspecting the `DBEngine.Errors` collection as explained in a related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29777147/2144390). I this case it showed me "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'junk' to data type int."

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

check your proper connection

**ODBC DSN**

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

var conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
              "Dsn=DsnName;" + 
              "Uid=UserName;" + 
              "Pwd=Secret;"; 
conn.Open();
```

**ODBC -- Standard Connection**

```
    using System.Data.Odbc;

    var conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = 
                  "Driver={SQL Server};" + 
                  "Server=DataBaseNamex;" + 
                  "DataBase=DataBaseName;" + 
                  "Uid=UserName;" + 
                  "Pwd=Secret;"; 
    conn.Open();
```

**ODBC -- Trusted Connection**

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

var conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
              "Driver={SQL Server};" + 
              "Server=ServerName;" + 
              "DataBase=DataBaseName;" + 
              "Uid=;" + 
              "Pwd=;"; 
conn.Open();

// or

var conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
              "Driver={SQL Server};" + 
              "Server=ServerName;" + 
              "DataBase=DataBaseName;" + 
              "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"; 
conn.Open();
```

Comment: Thanks Denish Parvadia, sorry for my unclear question, the ODBC connection is stable, I can run other code successfully with the same ODBC connection. I have edited the question to further illustrate the situation. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Denish Parvadia, I have run the query directly in the SQL Server instead of Acess, and SQL Server directly shows the exact cause of the problem. It is the data issue, it is now fixed. Thanks a lot for your time.