# Issue with ADOdb.connection.execute "create table" via MSAccess with Mysql backend

Tags: mysql, ms-access, adodb

So MSAccess 2010 using MySql back end, with a connection via ADODB.connection, a statement has this form:

```
...
Set cnx = Application.CurrentProject.connection

On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
If Not TableExistsADO(cnx, "fixedsampleresults") Then 
    createSpec = "CREATE TABLE `" & dbName & "`.`fixedsampleresults` ( " _
    & "`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL, " _
    & "`AreaID` INT(11) NULL, " _
    & "`RegionID` INT(11) NULL, " _
    & "`TopRating` INT(11) NOT NULL, " _
    & "`TotalRespondants` INT(11) NOT NULL, " _
    & "`Percentage` DECIMAL(5,3) NOT NULL, " _
    & "PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), " _
    & "UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC));" 

    cnx.Execute createSpec
...
end if
...
```

It is reaching the Execute line and failing with Error Message: "Run-time error -2147217900 (80040e14) Syntax error in Create Table statement".

I used the immediate window and debug.print to copy createSpec precisely, and entered and run this on a query tab in MySql Workbench without issue.

Are DataDefinition statements legitimate with Execute against a MySql or is this a difference in Access synatx requirements, or something else?

Comment: I don't think all the back ticks are required. To encapsulate `dbname` as a string use apostrophes `'dbname'`

Comment: No I didnt think so either. I originally set it without them - put them in simply in the hope it would resolve the issue - but it has made no difference, both ways produce the same result

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest as something to look at, is the `decimal ()` function. I am aware of the `INT()` function being correct, but I'm not sure about the `decimal()` one.

Comment: No I dont think this is it - removed the decimal line and still the same result!

Comment: You're right, I had a look and the `decimal` is correct. What happens if you get rid of the index? shouldn't the Primary key automatically index the records?

Comment: No this is not fixing things either - See response to @Gord Thompson below.

Answer (score 2):

In an Access application, `CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO connection to the *Access database* using Jet/ACE OLEDB. Therefore if you execute a CREATE TABLE statement against that connection it will be interpreted as Access SQL and will attempt to create a local Access table in the current database.

If you want to create a MySQL table then you'll need to use a pass-through query, something like this:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("anExistingLinkedTableInAccess").Connect
qdf.SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" & dbName & "`.`fixedsampleresults` ( " _
        & "`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL, " _
        & "`AreaID` INT(11) NULL, " _
        & "`RegionID` INT(11) NULL, " _
        & "`TopRating` INT(11) NOT NULL, " _
        & "`TotalRespondants` INT(11) NOT NULL, " _
        & "`Percentage` DECIMAL(5,3) NOT NULL, " _
        & "PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), " _
        & "UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC));" 
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Comment: Yes you are on the right lines - having removed all the column specs and just leaving create table only, it is ignoring the fact that it is linked MySql and erroring saying it cant find C:\......\cppqclientreplication.mdb So I guess this can be done with ADODb as well? I have seen an AdoDb example of similar - I believe (maybe wrongly) that it is not a good idead to mix ADO and DAO in the same applicaiton is that right?

Comment: Using a combination of DAO and ADO in the same application should not be a problem. The linked table from which you "steal" the `Connect` property should be an ODBC linked table pointing to a table in the MySQL database.

Comment: In practice though Execute is failing again though with run-time error 3146 ODBC - call failed. I had changed "anExistingLinkedTableInAccess" to "tblBranch" and verified the connection when the code hits the Execute line.

Comment: You can check the `DBEngine.Errors` collection to get more information on why the call failed. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29777147/2144390) for details.

Comment: (1103): [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.18-nt]Incorrect table name 'fixedsampleresults'
(3146): ODBC--call failed.

Comment: However there is a problem that the table most certainly is correctly named

Comment: As a workaround (which wont cut it for production) but ok to test manually I created the table. And run INSERT INTO cppqclientreplication.fixedsampleresults (...) SELECT ... and errors with exactly the same (1103): [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.18-nt]Incorrect table name 'fixedsampleresults' (3146): ODBC--call failed.

Comment: There must be some problem with the connection. I have just placed temp code Set cnx = Application.CurrentProject.connection On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER Dim rst As Recordset sql = "Select * From " & dbName & ".tblBranch" Set rst = cnx.Execute(sql) MsgBox "RowCount: " & rst.RecordCount It is still failing but producing an Invalid Argument error - There isnt a lot to be invlid: Select * from cppqclientreplication.tblBranch -

Comment: Anything that you do with `CurrentProject.Connection` will be operating on a table listed under "Tables" in the Access database, either a native Access table or a linked table. You can't directly manipulate tables on the MySQL server (e.g. dbname.tablename) via that connection.

Comment: But this is not working with the simple Select - yet the same module has many other Select queries working on exactly this basis.

Comment: If you are querying MySQL tables using `CurrentProject.Connection` then they must already be defined as linked tables in the Access database. (The linked tables in the Access database may have the same name as the tables in the MySQL database.)

Comment: Yes I understand this but without wishing to go off course from the pass-through solution you suggested; the simple SELECT test I mentionned IS based on a linked table already defined in the Access database. I didnt realise yesterday I had disrupted the error handling when including the loop for DBEngine.Errors - but putting that right this morning I find the simple test is falling over on is -2147467259 Could not find file 'C:\...\cppqclientreplication.mdb but the table I am using as mentionned is definitely a linked mysql table not a native.

Comment: It definitely exists on the Mysql cppqclientreplication db I can run the same query in workbench without issue. If I open the table in access it is working the connectionstring starts ODBC;DATABASE=cppqreplication...