# link ms access to sql server that uses ssl for encryption

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

We use a Microsoft Access database with linked tables to an SQL Server, and are working on encrypting data as it moves across the network. I have installed a certificate on a SQL Server (2014) that has been issued from a domain certificate server, and that is working fine except the links won't work now.  I haven't been able to find anything on how I may be able to get the linked tables working.

Comment: Do you receive an error message when you try to work with the linked tables? If so, and if it is the generic "ODBC--call failed" error then you might want to try the technique in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29777147/2144390) to see if you can get more information about the cause of the failure. FWIW, I just tried accessing a SQL Server 2014 instance configured for "Encryption required = Yes" and I was able to create a linked table in Access 2010 without incident even when using the ancient "SQL Server" ODBC driver.

Comment: Gord, you kind of put me on the right path.  I realized that the DSN that I was using was created prior to enforcing encryption.  I rebuilt the DSN, relinked the tables and it appears to be working.