# MS Access VBA & SQL Server - ODBC Call Failed on .Update of Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, ssms

I have an MS Access application that I'm converting to SQL Server Backend (still Access FE), with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

The application stores HR information and there is a function that is supposed to build probation schedule due dates based on employment date and probation period.

Here's the function:

```vba
Private Sub BtnBuildSked_Click()
    Const SUB_NAME As String = "BtnBuildSked_Click"
    On Error GoTo ErrCond
    Dim ThisReport, myresponse, MyStyle As Integer
    Dim MYDB As Database
    Dim Myrst, PdRec As DAO.Recordset
    'Dim Myfrm As Form
    Dim PdStr As String
    Dim s, strsql As String
    Dim t As TTracking
    
    If Me.PaysrID.Value = "ON LEAVE" Then
        MsgBox ("Record is marked ON LEAVE. Cannot proceed.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    'Set Myfrm = Screen.ActiveForm
    Set MYDB = CurrentDb
    s = "SELECT * FROM tblProbationReports"
    Set Myrst = MYDB.OpenRecordset(s, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    MyStyle = vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
    
    If IsNull(Me.PaysrID) Then
        MsgBox ("Cannot process for empty Employee ID")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If (IsNull(Me.ApptDate)) Then
        myresponse = MsgBox("Appointment Date field is empty ", vbCritical)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '----- Check that Probation Term ID is not blank
    If (Me.ProbationTermId.Value < 1 Or Me.ProbationTermId.Value > 7 Or IsNull(Me.ProbationTermId)) Then
        myresponse = MsgBox("You must select a probationary period to be able to build a schedule", MyStyle)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '----- Warning that any existing records for this employee will be deleted
    myresponse = MsgBox("Warning!! This will delete any current probation schedule records for this Employee and Line No. combination. Do you want to proceed  ?", vbYesNo)
    Debug.Print myresponse
    If myresponse = 7 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '------ Delete previous Probationary records for employee ; Keys = SS# and Line#
    strsql = "DELETE tblProbationReports.* " & _
             "FROM tblProbationReports " & _
             "WHERE tblProbationReports.LineNo= '" & Me.LineNo & "' and tblProbationReports.PaysrID = '" & Me.PaysrID & "' "
            
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strsql)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 
    '----- Point to the approp recoird in Probation Data
    PdStr = "SELECT * " & _
            "FROM [tblProbationData] " & _
            "WHERE [ProbationTermID] = " & Me.ProbationTermId.Value
            
    'Set PdRec = MYDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [tblProbationData] WHERE [ProbationTermID] = & me.ProbationTermID.Value & ")
    Set PdRec = MYDB.OpenRecordset(PdStr)
    If Not PdRec.EOF Then
        For ThisReport = 1 To PdRec("ProbationReports")
        
        'With Myrst
            Myrst.AddNew
            Myrst.Fields("LineNumber") = Me.LineNo
            Myrst.Fields("SSNO") = Me.SSNo
            Myrst.Fields("PaysrID") = Me.PaysrID
            Myrst.Fields("ReportNo") = ThisReport
            Select Case ThisReport
                Case 1
                    Myrst.Fields("FromDate") = Me.ApptDate
                    Myrst.Fields("ToDate") = Me.ApptDate + (PdRec("Report1weeks") * 7) '-1
                    Myrst.Fields("DueDate") = Me.ApptDate + (PdRec("Report1weeks") * 7) - 1 - 14
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + (PdRec("Report1weeks") * 7) - 1 - 28
                Case 2
                    Myrst.Fields("FromDate") = Me.ApptDate + (PdRec("Report1weeks") * 7)
                    Myrst.Fields("ToDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks")) * 7) '- 1
                    Myrst.Fields("DueDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 14
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 28
                Case 3
                    Myrst.Fields("FromDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks")) * 7)
                    Myrst.Fields("ToDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks")) * 7) '- 1
                    Myrst.Fields("DueDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 14
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 28
                Case 4
                    Myrst.Fields("FromDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks")) * 7)
                    Myrst.Fields("ToDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks")) * 7) '- 1
                    Myrst.Fields("DueDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 14
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 28
                Case 5
                    Myrst.Fields("FromDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks")) * 7)
                    Myrst.Fields("ToDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks")) * 7) '- 1
                    Myrst.Fields("DueDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 14
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 28
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 42
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 56
                Case 6
                    Myrst.Fields("FromDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks")) * 7)
                    Myrst.Fields("ToDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) '- 1
                    Myrst.Fields("DueDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 14
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 28
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 42
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 56
                Case 7
                    Myrst.Fields("FromDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks")) * 7)
                    Myrst.Fields("ToDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) '- 1
                    Myrst.Fields("DueDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 14
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 28
                    Myrst.Fields("SentDate") = Me.ApptDate + ((PdRec("Report1weeks") + PdRec("Report2weeks") + PdRec("Report3weeks") + PdRec("Report4weeks") + PdRec("Report5weeks") + PdRec("Report6weeks")) * 7) - 1 - 56
            End Select
            Myrst.Fields("Received") = False
            Myrst.Update
        
            
        'End With
        Next ThisReport
        
     End If
      
        'set up tracking manually
        t.Comment = "Build New Schedule"
        t.FieldName = "LineNo"
        t.ItemID = Me.LineNo
        t.NewValue = "New Schedule Built"
        t.OldValue = ""
        t.TableName = "tblProbationReports"
        t.TrackingType = TR_TYPE_NEW
        SaveTrans t
        
     Myrst.Close
     PdRec.Close
    
'Myfrm.SetFocus
Me.Recalc
MsgBox ("Probation dates created")



Exit Sub
ErrCond:
    EventLogging AppSession.UserName, MSG_TYPE_ERROR, Err.Number, Err.Description, MOD_NAME & "." & SUB_NAME, AppSession.AppSilent
End Sub
```

The first several blocks are checks for properly formatted employeeID, and active status.

Code warns that any new schedule will delete previous values.

Then the application is supposed to build the new schedule based on probation period (the various Case statements) and employment date.

But when the code drops to .Update, it fails with "ODBC Call Failed".

Here's a rundown of notes and troubleshooting thus far:

- Nothing wrong with the connection to the BE. I'm able to create, update, and delete employee records without issue. I can see data in the tables when opening via Access FE. I can run reports.
- "Probation Reports" table did not have a primary key, which I needed to add in order to create Audit triggers in SSMS (I know table should have primary key, but I wasn't the original developer).
- I made "RecordID" Primary Key in "Probation Reports" table and made it "Identity" in order to increment the unique identifier automatically.
- When making RecordID "Identity" to increment sequentially in SSMS, Access errored out on Recordset.Open of "Probation Reports" ... "table with identity needs dbSeeChanges on open of Recordset"
- Trying Recordset.Open ("name", ,dbSeeChanges) still errored out, "table with identity needs dbSeeChanges on open of Recordset". Access was not reading "dbSeeChanges" Option value
- I needed to add an open "Type" (although optional) in order for Access to read the open "Options" value of "dbSeeChanges".
- I've tried every value for Open "Type" learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-openrecordset-method-dao  (even ones that didn't make sense). This is where the .Update breaks with "ODBC Connection Failed"
- I tried adding LockEdit value option of "dbOpenOptimistic" and still getting the "ODBC Call Failed" error ...

I'm at a loss of where to go from here...

---

UPDATE - based on feedback in comments, I tried adding values to the table directly and received the following error (screenshot)[image: HR APP Error]

Comment: 1st thing to do: try editing + inserting in the linked table tblProbationData directly (in data sheet). You may get better error messages there.

Comment: @Andre - I'll try that right now. 2 mins.

Comment: @Andre - that was definitely a different error! I'm going to update the question with this, and the screenshot. Something about binary truncation...

Comment: In VBA you need to have the data type for each variable in Dim statements. `Dim Myrst, PdRec As DAO.Recordset` => `Myrst` will be Variant, not Recordset. Shouldn't matter here, but still.

Comment: @Andre - I'll keep that in mind with Myrst. I don't believe that's the issue, though, as this worked and works fine with the MS Access BE. Unless this is a change I have to make because of how this would translate to SSMS(?)

Comment: Yes, it's just good coding skill to have correct data types. See here to get behind "ODBC call failed": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774178/odbc-call-failed-with-stored-procedure-pass-through-query -- it should give the same error you got manually. Google will help with that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is/was actually one of the fields in this db (and subsequent code above): "LineNo"

"LineNo" is a RESERVED WORD in SQL Server.

After implementing all sorts of suggestions, this one crept up from ....I don't even remember where but here's an article of reserved words in SQL Server for future reference for others:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Changing ALL references to this field from "LineNo" to "LineNum" resolved all errors.

Answer (score 1):

To define recordsets (both in access, and when using sql server).

```
Dim rst      AS DAO.Reocdset
```

you can leave out the DAO. but you should not.

For ANY linked sql server table?

That table MUST have a PK defined. If you open the access linked table in design mode (ignore the ready only warning), then check TWO things:

First, be 100% if not 200% sure you see a PK defined.

Second: while you at this, check the data types for datetime columns. If they are text in place of date time, you MUST STOP NOW and fix that issue.

If the datetime columns are seen as text, then  you have two choices:

Change the sql server column data types from datetime2 (the new default) to datetime and then re-link tables. Now check again with table in design as per aobve - check the column data types.

You can also consider installing the newer ODBC Native 11 or later drivers - they support datetime2 - the built in legacy ODBC driver does NOT!!! - it see those columns as text. But, the downside is that you have to install the native 11 (or later driver - now at verison 17) on EACH workstation. So, it up to you which is less hassle (install native drivers on each workstation, or flip the sql server column times back to datetime and NOT use datetime2).

Next issue.

Access open a table:

```
Dim  rst   AS DAO.RecordSet

set rst = currentdb.OpenReocrdSet(" table name or sql goes here")
```

Access open a linked table to sql server.

```
   Dim rst             As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL          As String
   
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblInvoice where InvoiceNum = " & InvoiceNumber
   
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

So, you ALWAYS include dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges

If you just done a access to sql server migration? Then I find EVEN in a relative large application, using global search and replace, (with ,dbOpenDynaset,dbSeeChanges in my paste buffer? It should not take more then say about 5 minutes of time. so go change all VBA reocrdset code that NOW operates on linked tables.

So, you have to add/have/include the two extra parms on recordset open like this:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

A few more got ya's

All bit fields MUST HAVE a default value set (say 0) for false in the sql server table designs.

If you are receiving the dreaded "someone else has updated" the record errors? Then you need to add a timestamp column to that table (do NOT confusing timestamp with a date time - the timestamp is what we call a row-version column - has zero to do with date-time, and you never touch or edit or change that row-version column.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. UpVoted because your response has a LOT of useful/helpful tips that are invaluable. And, if anyone else is going through this conversion as we are I think they'd appreciate not having to learn this all the hard way as we have (and still having to in some ways). Thanks!