# ODBC--call failed - MSAccess linked table to mysql view

Tags: view, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access front end database linked to tables and views on remote mysql database.
It's in use for many months. Since yesterday when trying to open tables linked to views MS Access is raising the error "ODBC--call failed". The tables linked to remote tables are working normally. The views on the remote database are working normally in phpMyAdmin and HeidiSQL. I tried to import a view into local table in MS Access and it works, creating the local table with the data which is visible in the phpMyAdmin and HeidiSQL. The issue is the same on several PC in different physical locations.
Any suggestions why there will be problems only with the tables linked to the remote views?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777147/2144390) may help with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

After digging out the specific ODBC error in MS Access, I got "Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared". Searching for this error, got me to [How to get rid of MySQL error 'Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380813/how-to-get-rid-of-mysql-error-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared)

Although the solution advised is to increase table cache, the simpler solution, pointed out in one to answers, that worked for me was to issue the command:

flush tables;

In case none of those work, you might be able to solve the issue by using an ODBC query to the view instead of creating a link to the view.

I suppose this error comes up due to upgrades of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm from the hosting company, if there is a change in connection strings required to access database on your account, or check the server where mysql/phpmyadmin is installed for changes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for the suggestion. I contacted the hosting company and they claim that no changes has been made on the server side. And that they have no explanation for this error. It is very strange. Why would the linked tables have no issue opening but the linked views cannot be opened?

Comment: I have the same problem, no clue what is wrong, no real error info. But at least it is possible to workaround by creating an ODBC query to SELECT the view. That works.

Comment: there is a relevant bug report here:https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91532