ODBC connection failure between Access frontend database and MySQL
A new Windows laptop has 64 bit Connector/ODBC 8.4.0 installed, using the same procedure for other computers in the same company. When I open a linked table I get the rather unhelpful message "ODBC call failed".  No error number. I am using User DSN and have not changed any settings in the Details section, the only boxed ticked is the "Disable schema support" on the Metadata tab.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the ODBC software, no change.  One thing I did notice is that if I import the tables instead of linking to them, the data pops into the front end database without any errors.  Unfortunately I do need to create a link and not import the tables.  I have used the procedure on other computers without a problem.  I have copied the front end of one computer which works and still get the error, so I think it must be to do with the installation of ODBC software on this laptop.
None of the other computers running the same front-end  Access database  and with same version of ODBC installed have this problem.  I can convert a linked table to a local table and all the data shows up correctly.  When I open the link table all fields are filled with #NAME.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777147/2144390

Thank you @GordThompson I managed to get the following error information: (2031): [MySQL][ODBC 8.4(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.5.25-MariaDB-ubu2004]No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
(3146): ODBC--call failed.
I then removed the 8.4 ODBC driver and installed 9.0, but no change same error.  I am wondering if I should go back to version 5.3?

I am going to investigate Method 4 onwards here https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-ms-access-runtime-error-3146-odbc-call-failed/

Your error message says MariaDB. Maybe MySQL Connector/ODBC doesn't like it so much any more …?

It is definitely an issue with the laptop.  I copied the front end database to my laptop and it worked.
